# C++ code obfuscator

Tags: c++, obfuscation

Are there programs available that can obfuscate C++ code, so it becomes very hard to read, but at the same time, the behavior of the compiled binary doesn't change, and there is none or negligible performance loss.

**Note:** There is already a question asked at StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code. But it's closed as off-topic there.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use global replaces to:

1. Remove all comments
2. Remove all blank lines
3. Remove 3/4 of other line feeds
4. Replace all function names, (except main), with Fnnnn *where nnnn is a 4 digit number*
5. Take random chunks of code and move them into macro definitions
6. Replace all variable names with Vnnnnnn *where nnnnnn is a 6 digit number*
7. Rename all Classes Cnnnn
8. Rename all defines with Dnnnnn
9. Rename all the files Fnnnn

That will give you a fair degree of obfuscation, *(just like the code written by* ***some*** *of the people that I have worked with - maybe you should just hire some of them)*.

Depending on your tool chain you could also compile your code to ASM output with full optimisation turned on and then reverse engineer portions of your code to the way that the optimiser does it.

Comment: And having manually done all this once, you now modify your original source code.

Comment: You can easily have a set of either editor macros, or better yet python scripts, to do this for you!

Comment: Changing the formatting is pointless, as there are tools which can put it into proper formatting and indentation. Stripping the function and variable names, and removing the comments does make sense, though.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the only relevant answer from the StackOverflow question:

[Mangle-It C++ Code Obfuscator](http://www.pcsentinelsoftware.com/products/mangleit/mangler_cpp_new_proj.htm) is paid software, licenses are for $69.99.

Comment: http://www.stunnix.com/prod/cxxo/overview.shtml - $369

Comment: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CppObfuscationExample.html - $750

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered a quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. An answer should e.g. explicitely point out how the recommended product matches the requirements, and what makes it recommendable.